# Multi container pod with command sleep k8

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying out mock exams on udemy and have created a multi container pod . but exam result says command is not set correctly on container `test2` .I am not able to identify the issue.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: multi-pod
  name: multi-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: test1
    env:
     - name: type
       value: demo1
  - image: busybox
    name: test2
    env:
     - name: type
        value: demo2
    command: ["sleep", "4800"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is by using imperative kubectl command to generate the yaml for a single container and edit the yaml to add the other container

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --command -oyaml --dry-run=client -- sh -c 'sleep 1d' > nginx.yaml
```

In this example `sleep 1d` is the command.

The generated yaml looks like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - sleep 1d
    image: nginx
    name: nginx
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: One way is to use Falco..https://github.com/falcosecurity/charts

Comment: I am preparing for CKAD so would like to know without any extra libraries

Comment: You can just say 1m and wait for 1m to see if the pod terminates or not and then increase 1m to whatever is asked in the exam

Comment: running kubectl exec multipod -c test2 gives error: you must specify at least one command for the container

Comment: Try this way `kubectl exec multipod -c test2 -- sh ls`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your **YAML in line 19.**

Please keep in mind that `YAML` syntax is very sensitive for spaces and tabs.

Your issue:

```
  - image: busybox
    name: test2
    env:
     - name: type
        value: demo2     ### Issue is in this line, you have one extra space
    command: ["sleep", "4800"]
```

**Solution:**

Remove space, it wil looks like that:

```
    env:
     - name: type
       value: demo2
```

For validation of `YAML` you can use external validators like [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/).

If you would paste your `YAML` to mentioned validator, you will receive error:

```
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 19 column 14
```

After removing this extra space you will get

```
Valid YAML!
```