# Can Docker automatically create personalized/dynamic containers in run-time?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I am working on an application that will allow users to submit their python scripts. These python scripts will contain Language Models (LMs) that will be used by the app to calculate certain metrics.

I was planning on running these scripts inside Docker containers, for scalability and security concerns. They would function as "black-boxes" that would accept an input and return an output without the app needing to know what is going on inside the container.

For now, I simply need to get a proof-of-concept working, and I assumed that Docker allowed users to not only create containers manually, but also automatically. After hours of searching, I believe I was proven wrong. I have read about something called Kubernetes, but I am unsure if this is what I need.

So my question is simple: Is it possible to use *only* Docker for this, or do I need to learn other tools like Kubernetes to do this?

### **Additional Context**

I've thought about (for just the proof-of-concept) to use a python program that calls the submitted code, but I have no idea how it would install the necessary packages from the submitted code's imports. I also don't know how I would keep the code running, as LMs need to stay loaded to run, and if script1.py calls script2.py, it won't keep executing until script2.py is done running, meaning I would have to wait for the LM to load every time I need to call its functions.
Also, I already have a docker-compose.yml file that automatically installs all the dependencies and containerizes the submitted python scripts, but it must be run manually.

If you would like to look at some of the code for the containerization:

This creates a container with the script that acts as a middleman between the LM and the server, and automatically installs the required dependencies of the LM.

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/app/src

COPY communicator.py ./
COPY lm_submission.py ./
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

This docker-compose file manually creates the "server" (the thing that gives inputs to the LMs and waits for outputs) and the communicator (in theory, there would be lots of communicators running multiple LMs and 1 server. Also the `chatGPT_roberta_model` parameter would be a variable name that changes depending on the name of the LM being run).

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  communicator:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "sleep 2s; python3 ./communicator.py chatGPT_roberta_model"
    environment:
      LISTEN_HOST: server
      LISTEN_PORT: 5555
    ports:
      - '5556:5555'
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    build: ./server/
    command: sh -c "python3 ./server.py"
    environment:
      SEND_HOST: server
      SEND_PORT: 5555
    ports:
      - '5555:5555'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically" creating a container?  Kubernetes has some autoscaling capabilities that can create more copies of a container (typically a long-running server container) in response to load. In general, though, I'd suggest against implementations that depend on dynamically creating containers.

Comment: By automatically, I mean that the server code should have a function that is called when a python script is submitted that automatically creates a container with that script running inside it.
Also, what do you mean you suggest against dynamically creating containers? I've seen programs that only succeed by containerizing user-submitted code (because the code may be malicious or for other reasons), it is absolutely possible and probably the best way to tackle the problem I have.

Comment: How do you plan to keep track of the containers you create?  In pure Docker, the ability to create a container comes with unrestricted root-level access over the host; how will you secure your application code?  What will you do if the controller process fails?  How will you protect against workloads like cryptocurrency miners, or attacks directly against the host kernel?  (Running actually-untrusted code is a hard problem.)

Comment: The LMs will first be tested. There has to be an actual good and accurate language model in the code before it gets approved to be in our server. There will also be other metrics like the time it takes to process text or how much CPU it uses. Also, don't all the other concerns that you have also apply to non-black box methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the right tools, it takes relatively little time to prepare your POC.

I suggest you start exploring minikube, which is a lite and portable version of Kubernetes perfect for this type of use-case.

Take a look here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Obviously, the Companies have Cloud Providers or large Kubernetes Clusters of tests available for these needs; minikube is more of something for the laboratory.

(I speak of Kubernetes because, as a container orchestrator, it is certainly the best choice and closest to a possible production use-case)

Then find out about the Kubernetes Deployment and Service resources, in order to release your "black-box" application.
The Deployment will allow you to release 1 or more Pods (instances of your application + OS + Network) and the Service will allow you to make the application reachable inside the K8s Cluster and/or outside.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

It will then be possible to ensure that these application instances (Pods) remain up&running and always available for the end-user by following a few simple steps --> [Multi container pod with command sleep k8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475195/multi-container-pod-with-command-sleep-k8)

Finally, I suggest not to create containers with active root users (if possible) and to prevent users from accessing these Pods via SSH; surely a better solution could be to develop a front-end.

PS: If you don't know how to generate Kubernetes manifests, you can convert Docker Compose manifests simply --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/